# AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED error when running Strongloop with PM2 in cluster mode

Tags: cluster-computing, restful-authentication, strongloop, pm2, angular-fullstack

### I'm running Strongloop using PM2 as my process manager.

- **pm2 start server/server.js -i 0** (starts strongloop in cluster mode).
- **pm2 list** (shows me two instances of server with different PID).
  [pm2 list image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSUMX.png)

---

**In my Angular-fullstack application:**

- **Run a POST** call with email and password to get token, ttl etc.
  *Response was correct:* `{"id":"z2MgpdN2dyXHHWw2DLhAI026vHBgxw43jpCz9khWa7U9GykAmnQZAaeXV2nvEvQ8","ttl":1209600,"created":"2016-07-21T16:47:34.020Z","userId":"571609e4c88c6db26b75aacd"}`
- **Run a GET** call using the id (token) to get more information about the user: `http://myrestservice.com:3000/api/Users/571609e4c88c6db26b75aacd?access_token=z2MgpdN2dyXHHWw2DLhAI026vHBgxw43jpCz9khWa7U9GykAmnQZAaeXV2nvEvQ8`
  *The response was Error 401 AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED*

---

**Question!!:**
How can I configure StrongLoop to handle with multiple instances of the same server/server.js ?
I read about to configure stored REDIS session, but the guides talks about Express + REDIS stored session management. I think this is a different approach.

---

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are not persisting your AccessTokens on a common dataSource for all your running servers/processes.

Try inspecting your `model-config.json` file and verify the dataSource for the AccessToken model is shared.

This will probably NOT be shared between all your servers/processes:

```
"AccessToken": {
  "dataSource": "memory",
  "public": false
},
```

This WILL be shared between all your servers/processes:

```
"AccessToken": {
  "dataSource": "mysqlDs",
  "public": false
},
```

*Where mysqlDs is stored on MySQL

This is the relevant section of the Loopback docs to configuring datasources https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Attaching+models+to+data+sources#Attachingmodelstodatasources-Makethemodelusethedatasource

Comment: this exactly answer my question!. Thanks a lot!. In my case: "dataSource":"gpds-db" points to mongodb